# Trying to convert an XML file to a different xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform the XML to an output that looks like another XML. I am not sure of how to print 'forward slash' though.
I need the output to have the tags also.
This is the xml file that I have to convert

```html
    <ItemDetails>
    <Item>
        <Code>3390876231</Code>
        <Customer id='1055'>
            <FirstName>John</FirstName>
            <MiddleName>M</MiddleName>
            <LastName>Crusoe</LastName>
            <Title>Mr.</Title>
            <Address>
                <HouseNumber>House11</HouseNumber>
                <Street>St.Marks Street</Street>
                <Country>UK</Country>
                <ContactNumber>
                    <PhoneNumber1>0657385245</PhoneNumber1>
                    <PhoneNumber2>0657385211</PhoneNumber2>
                </ContactNumber>
                <PostalCode>3452DD</PostalCode>
            </Address>
        </Customer>
        <Name>Romeo and Juliet</Name>
        <Type>compact disc</Type>
        <Author>Rostropovich</Author>
        <ListPrice>18.98</ListPrice>
        <SellPrice>13.99</SellPrice>
        <Cost>9.92</Cost>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Code>3390007231</Code>
        <Customer id='1056'>
            <FirstName>Kayne</FirstName>
            <MiddleName/>
            <LastName>West</LastName>
            <Title>Mr.</Title>
            <Address>
                <HouseNumber>House78</HouseNumber>
                <Street>Pittsburg Street</Street>
                <Country>USA</Country>
                <ContactNumber>
                    <PhoneNumber1>0690885245</PhoneNumber1>
                    <PhoneNumber2>0690785211</PhoneNumber2>
                </ContactNumber>
                <PostalCode>3882PP</PostalCode>
            </Address>
        </Customer>
        <Name>XSLT</Name>
        <Type>book</Type>
        <Author>Tidwell</Author>
        <ListPrice>49.95</ListPrice>
        <SellPrice>34.99</SellPrice>
        <Cost>22.92</Cost>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Code>3390876001</Code>
        <Customer id='1057'>
            <FirstName>Martha</FirstName>
            <MiddleName>W</MiddleName>
            <LastName>Hamilton</LastName>
            <Title>Mrs.</Title>
            <Address>
                <HouseNumber>House456</HouseNumber>
                <Street>Alfred Street</Street>
                <Country>UK</Country>
                <ContactNumber>
                    <PhoneNumber1>0659985245</PhoneNumber1>
                    <PhoneNumber2>0657300011</PhoneNumber2>
                </ContactNumber>
                <PostalCode>3786CD</PostalCode>
            </Address>
        </Customer>
        <Name>The Little Schemer</Name>
        <Type>book</Type>
        <Author>Friedman</Author>
        <Author>Felleisen</Author>
        <ListPrice>29.95</ListPrice>
        <SellPrice>26.99</SellPrice>
        <Cost>17.92</Cost>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Code>3399996231</Code>
        <Customer id='1058'>
            <FirstName>Harold</FirstName>
            <MiddleName/>
            <LastName>Crossley</LastName>
            <Title>Mr.</Title>
            <Address>
                <HouseNumber>House909</HouseNumber>
                <Street>Beaumont Street</Street>
                <Country>UK</Country>
                <ContactNumber>
                    <PhoneNumber1>0656665245</PhoneNumber1>
                    <PhoneNumber2>0657385200</PhoneNumber2>
                </ContactNumber>
                <PostalCode>3772DI</PostalCode>
            </Address>
        </Customer>
        <Name>A Tribute to People’s Princess: Diana</Name>
        <Type>book</Type>
        <Author>Peter Donelli</Author>
        <ListPrice>65.98</ListPrice>
        <SellPrice>78.99</SellPrice>
        <Cost>60.92</Cost>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Code>33908755118</Code>
        <Customer id='1059'>
            <FirstName>Donna</FirstName>
            <MiddleName>H</MiddleName>
            <LastName>Miller</LastName>
            <Title>Miss</Title>
            <Address>
                <HouseNumber>House998</HouseNumber>
                <Street>Maple Street</Street>
                <Country>USA</Country>
                <ContactNumber>
                    <PhoneNumber1>8002255288</PhoneNumber1>
                    <PhoneNumber2>8011155288</PhoneNumber2>
                </ContactNumber>
                <PostalCode>3662DD</PostalCode>
            </Address>
        </Customer>
        <Name>KingMozart</Name>
        <Type>compact disc</Type>
        <Author>Donald Runnicles</Author>
        <ListPrice>20.98</ListPrice>
        <SellPrice>18.99</SellPrice>
        <Cost>22.92</Cost>
    </Item>
</ItemDetails>
```

This is how the output should be. The nested tags to be removed and synced in a sequence.

```html
<ItemDetails>
    <Item>
        <Code>3390876231</Code>
        <CustomerID>1055</CustomerID>
        <FullName>Mr.John M Crusoe</FullName>
        <Address>House11,St.Marks Street,UK</Address>
        <ContactNumbers>0657385245,0657385211</ContactNumbers>
        <PostalCode>3452DD</PostalCode>
        <ItemName>Romeo and Juliet</ItemName>
        <ItemType>compact disc</ItemType>
        <Author>Rostropovich</Author>
        <list-price>18.98</list-price>
        <sell-price>13.99</sell-price>
        <cost-price>9.92</cost-price>
        <profit>4.07</profit>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Code>3390007231</Code>
        <CustomerID>1056</CustomerID>
        <FullName>Mr.Kayne West</FullName>
        <Address>House78,Pittsburg Street,USA</Address>
        <ContactNumbers>0690885245</ContactNumbers>
        <PostalCode>3882PP</PostalCode>
        <ItemName>XSLT</ItemName>
        <ItemType>book</ItemType>
        <Author>Tidwell</Author>
        <list-price>49.95</list-price>
        <sell-price>34.99</sell-price>
        <cost-price>22.92</cost-price>
        <profit>12.07</profit>
    </Item>
</ItemDetails>
```

And this is my code. I am not sure how to include the tags in the output

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <html>
   <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="Item">
  <p>&lt;Code&gt;<xsl:value-of select="Code"/>&lt;/Code&gt;</br>
  &lt;CustomerID&gt;<xsl:value-of select="Customer"/>&lt;/CustomerID&gt;</br>
  <xsl:for-each select="Customer">
  &lt;CustomerID&gt;<xsl:value-of select="Customer/@id"/>&lt;/CustomerID&gt;</br>
  &lt;FullName&gt;<xsl:value-of select="Title"/> <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/> <xsl:value-of select="MiddleName"/> <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>&lt;/FullName&gt; </br>
  &lt;Address&gt;
    <xsl:for-each select="Address">
      <xsl:value-of select="HouseNumber"/> <xsl:value-of select="Street"/> <xsl:value-of select="Country"/> &lt;/Address&gt; </br>
  &lt;ContactNumbers&gt;<xsl:for-each select="ContactNumber"> <xsl:value-of select="PhoneNumber1"/> , <xsl:value-of select="PhoneNumber2"/> </xsl:for-each>&lt;/ContactNumbers&gt; </br>
  &lt;PostalCode&gt;<xsl:value-of select="PostalCode"/>&lt;/PostalCode&gt;</br>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
  &lt;ItemName&gt;<xsl:value-of select="Name"/>&lt;/ItemName&gt;</br>
  &lt;ItemType&gt;<xsl:value-of select="Type"/>&lt;/ItemType&gt;</br>
  &lt;Author&gt;<xsl:value-of select="Author"/>&lt;/Author&gt;</br>
  &lt;list-price&gt;<xsl:value-of select="ListPrice"/>&lt;/list-price&gt;</br>
  &lt;sell-price&gt;<xsl:value-of select="SellPrice"/>&lt;sell-price&gt;</br>
  &lt;cost-price&gt;<xsl:value-of select="Cost"/>&lt;/cost-price&gt;</br></p>
 </xsl:for-each>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You have shown the desired output as XML, however the XSLT that you have tried contains `html`. Do you need XML or HTML as output?

Comment: @AniketV I want the output of the XSLT to look like the xml.

Comment: So what exactly does the XSLT code you have posted have to do with your question? Are you just posting any random code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below XSLT to get the desired output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="space" select="' '" />
    <xsl:variable name="comma" select="','" />

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item">
        <xsl:copy>
            <Code><xsl:value-of select="Code" /></Code>
            <CustomerID><xsl:value-of select="Customer/@id" /></CustomerID>
            <FullName>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(Customer/Title, $space, Customer/FirstName, $space, Customer/MiddleName, $space, Customer/LastName)" />
            </FullName>
            <Address>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(Customer/Address/HouseNumber, $comma, Customer/Address/Street, $comma, Customer/Address/Country)" />
            </Address>
            <ContactNumbers>
                <xsl:for-each select="Customer/Address/ContactNumber/*[contains(local-name(),'PhoneNumber')]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$comma" />
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ContactNumbers>
            <PostalCode><xsl:value-of select="Customer/Address/PostalCode" /></PostalCode>
            <ItemName><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></ItemName>
            <ItemType><xsl:value-of select="Type" /></ItemType>
            <Author><xsl:value-of select="Author" /></Author>
            <list-price><xsl:value-of select="ListPrice" /></list-price>
            <sell-price><xsl:value-of select="SellPrice" /></sell-price>
            <cost-price><xsl:value-of select="Cost" /></cost-price>
            <profit><xsl:value-of select="format-number(SellPrice - Cost, '0.##')" /></profit>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I need to include the tags too. Your answer was helpful though

Comment: Which tags need to be included? The output from the XSLT matches to the output shared by you.

Comment: I have edited my question. You can check the edit before the second code